# Docusign Connect - Client is behind firewall

Tags: docusignapi

I need to configure docusign connect to push notifications to my application server, however it is behind a firewall.  I do have a proxy but I dont see any options for configuring a proxy in the connect settings.  Any advice on how to proceed with this?

Comment: This question is probably a https://superuser.com topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to  configuring a proxy in the DocuSign connect settings.

Here are some of the requirements for DocuSign connect.

- Your app must include a listener HTTPS URL that DocuSign can POST to.
- This URL must be available on the public internet.
- It can’t be blocked by a firewall.

Here is good DocuSign [blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/) post which discusses options when your listener is behind a firewall. Here are some of the options posted in the blog post.

> - You can install your listener on a Heroku, Amazon, Azure or private server that is available on the internet.
> - you can use a service such as ngrok to tunnel the incoming requests to your machine which is behind your fire wall.
> - Your server can be located on your organization’s DMZ, providing access to the internet.
> - Your firewall can be opened (a “pinhole opening”) to enable the incoming notification requests from DocuSign to reach your listener.

You will need to work with your IT and InfoSec departments to determine the best answer for your configuration.